# how do a shim a constructor in VB?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-fakes

I an trying to get a Shimed Constructor to work in VB. I was able to do it in C#, but I need a VB example. The code I have below complies, but the Tests fail as the MyCalc.Total call does not use the Shim.

```
Using ShimsContext.Create()
  Calc.Fakes.ShimVBCalc.Constructor = Function() New Calc.Fakes.ShimVBCalc() With {
         .TotalGet = Function()
            Return 5.0
          End Function}
End Using
MyRealCalc = New Calc.VBCalc()
Assert.AreEqual(5,MyRealCalc.Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation code needs to be inside the using statement, otherwise you are calling the real Calc.VbCalc method.  Change your code to be:

```
Using ShimsContext.Create()
  Calc.Fakes.ShimVBCalc.Constructor = Function() New   Calc.Fakes.ShimVBCalc() With {
         .TotalGet = Function()
        Return 5.0
      End Function}
MyRealCalc = New Calc.VBCalc()
Assert.AreEqual(5,MyRealCalc.Total)
End Using
```